# Cannot Click on the button with Imacros

Tags: imacros

I cannot find a way to click on the button on Google Drive to click "File upload"
in Inspect element cannot find the exactly class which is changing every time,
trued to record with all kind of style but still not working.

Would be great if some one can check and figure out how it can be clicked.
Thank You in advance.

```
URL GOTO=https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR="#drive_main_page>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV" BUTTON=0
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:*-v&&ROLE:menuitem&&ID::4b
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=* CONTENT=C:\Users\Viktor\Documents\iMacros\Downloads\Folder\1.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution seems to work somehow:

```
' text for English as default language '
SET txtUpload "Upload files..."

URL GOTO=https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#drive_main_page>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>svg>polygon" BUTTON=0
WAIT SECONDS=0.5
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:{{txtUpload}} EXTRACT=HTM
SET id EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/id=\"(.+?)\"/)[1];")
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#\\{{id}}>DIV>SPAN:nth-of-type(2)>SPAN>DIV" BUTTON=0

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=* CONTENT=C:\Users\Viktor\Documents\iMacros\Downloads\Folder\1.png
```

Comment: Thank You it's working bu only one problem it not closing the popup upload window, after it repeats its opening new one and again not closing it. How can i fix it?

Comment: I wrote that it works only so-so. Really have no idea how to fix this issue. Perhaps someone else will help you out with the code.